# isSorted method not working for all cases...not sure why

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Here is the basic form of the question:

Write a method called isSorted that accepts an array of doubles as a parameter and returns true if they are sorted or false if they are not.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isSorted(double[] a){
   if (a.length == 1){
      return true;
   }
   boolean apples = false;
   int i = 1;
   while (i <= a.length-1){
      if (a[i] > a[i-1]){
         apples = true;
      } else {
         apples = false;
      }
      i++;
   }
   return apples;
}
```

when passed a double array {16.1, 12.3, 22.2, 14.4}, {1.5, 4.3, 7.0, 19.5, 25.1, 46.2}, or {42.0}, it returns false, true, true respectively. However, when passed an array {1.5, 4.3, 7.0, 19.5, 7.8, 25.1, 46.2}, it returns true when it should return false.

Comment: the way it is right now, you're returning the value based only on whether the last item is greater than the second to last item. what you want to do is assume it is sorted, then stop checking as soon as something isn't in the right order and return false

Comment: in the "else { apples = false; }" it should be "else { return false; }". Really you just need to loop through and return false if it's NOT sorted and just "return true" at the end. You're also not handling the case when two elements are equal.

Comment: You're also not handling the case when an empty list is passed in.

Answer (score 4):

Later cases of `a[i] > a[i-1]` (`=> apples = true`) are overwriting cases of `apples` being set to false. There's no need to keep iterating after you've found a single case where `a[i]` isn't less than `a[i+1]`.

#### Other cleanup

- This is a use case where a `for` loop is cleaner to use than a `while` loop.
- You should handle empty arrays.
- Assuming the array might contain repeated elements, you need to (correctly) handle the case where `a[i] === a[i-1]`.

This method does all of the above:

```
public static boolean isSorted(double[] a){
    if (a.length < 2) return true;
    
    for (int i=1; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (a[i] < a[i-1]){
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

<sub>***Edit:*** oh, and why did you name the return variable `apples`? It doesn't make any sense in the context of the method, and hints at sloppy coding.</sub>

Comment: I wasn't sure what to name it, and it was for an exercise in my book. If there are lots of things that I need to keep track of in a complex program I will use names that make sense, but if it is a simple method like this then I don't see any reason not to have a little fun. Besides, it makes it a little easier to follow for me.

Answer (score 2):

After assigning `apples = false;` in `else`, there is no need to iterate further. Just place `break` in `else`.

Comment: D'oh, see it now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user - I was actually writing an explanation with the examples you have given. It seems you understood where the logic is going wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Almost good, I propose to add break:

```
  if (a[i] > a[i-1]){
     apples = true;
  } else {
     apples = false;
     break; // <--
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning the result of the LAST comparison, as you don't exit when detecting an out-of-order condition.

Answer (score 0):

When if false you have to break or return.